# Any div or span i click on always highlights a gridview, WHY?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, html, designview

In Visual Studio 2010 if I click on any `<div>` or `<span>` anywhere in the design view it selects this one grid always. Has anyone ever seen this? Are there any ways to fix this?

The only controls in design view that I can click on are textboxes / dropdowns / buttons / linkbuttons etc. So when I want to quickly jump to a span to edit its contents I have to click on the nearest one of those controls then make my way over to the `<span>`. Cause if I click on the `<span>`, BOOM highlight the gridview. It is driving me insane!

*UPDATE*

when i exceed 17 columns in the gridview this is happening. anything less than 17 does not cause this issue. i'd say this is a bug, and after a certain amount of columns the gridview does not function properly in design view and throws off other elements in the page.

Comment: Also, There are 1800 lines of markup so I will not be posting it. Just wondering if this is a known bug someone knows about in VS design view, not asking for help with my code, the code is working fine itself... thanks.

Comment: Be like Tank from the Matrix and look at the code instead.  Never have to worry about that issue.

Comment: Work with the code view instead; you'll have full power. I forgot when I used the design view last :)

Comment: With 1800 lines of code (and growing) it is nice to be able to click on the span i need to edit instead of finding it in code. I am looking for a way to not have to do that, but thanks for the suggestion. @mshsayem

Comment: When there is too much markup/codes, I normally break it (if possible) into smaller parts(using `UserControls`, master pages or other server controls). Design view has issues to discourage anybody (for example, if you have base class extending `Page`, and your aspx pages extends that class, design view wont work without some tweaks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done do "work around" this problem.

It is a design view problem, not code.

Any time you have a grid view that has enough fields to push if off to the right of the visible editing area in design view, this bug will occur. Clicking spans and divs will always highlight that grid, it is so annoying.

You can expand your design view window wide enough to see the entire grid and this problem goes away for the time being. it is extremely annoying but works.

i am sure there are other work arounds but i have not seen anyone else have this problem (most people dont use the design view).